# SQL Join a row table with a column table

Tags: sql, join, row

I have two tables that I’m trying to connect (join). Table1 is a column table as follows:

| id | Phone | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 123456 | Maria | Abc |
| 102 | 234567 | Daniel | Def |

Table 2 is a row table as follows:

| id | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Manager | Rudolf |
| 101 | Account | 456 |
| 101 | Code | B |
| 102 | Manager | Anna |
| 102 | Code | B |
| 102 | Code | C |

The result I’m looking for is:

| id | Phone | Name | Description | Manager | Account | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 123456 | Maria | Abc | Rudolf | 456 | B |
| 102 | 234567 | Daniel | Def | Anna |  | B,C |

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks to Gordon for the table-formatting. Did you try anything already, then [edit] and post your [example], please. It will help us to spot your issue and help!

Comment: I forgot!. The Code attribute is a multirow row value that I want to be comma separated instead. Sorry!

Comment: Maybe it would help to give your _tables_ meaningful names (e.g. _employee_ for `table2`). Then you can __describe their relationship__ to us: see [ER model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table thrice (using different aliases). For example:

```
select
  p.*,
  a.value as Manager,
  b.value as Account,
  c.value as Cardno
from table1 p
left join table2 a on a.id = p.id and a.attribute = 'Manager'
left join table2 b on b.id = p.id and b.attribute = 'Account'
left join table2 c on c.id = p.id and b.attribute = 'Cardno'
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: select *  
from
(
    select distinct t1.id,t1.attribute,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.value, 120)
          FROM table1 t2
          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.attribute=t2.attribute
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS value
from table1 t1
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for attribute in (manager,account,cardno,code)
) piv

Comment: @Mikael If this is SQL-code you tried, perfect! Add it to your question with a brief explanation what needs to be improved

Answer (score 0):

You should use 3 times table 2 for get the 3 attributes  inner for manager (alway matching) and left join for  Account  and CardNo (not always matching)

```
select a.id, a.phone, a.Name, a.Description b.value, c.value
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b ON a.id = b.id and b.attribute = 'Manager' 
left  join table2 c ON a.id = c.id and c.attribute = 'Account' 
left join table2 d ON a.id = d.id and d.attribute = 'CardNo'
```

Comment: Are the syntax-errors in SELECT list and "no boss"-restriction by INNER JOIN didactically intended? 

Answer (score 0):

If you have only three unique attribute in your "row table" than you can use subqueries like this:

```
SELECT 
t.*,
(SELECT t2.Value FROM Table2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.Attribute='Manager') as Manager,
(SELECT t2.Value FROM Table2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.Attribute='Account') as Account, 
(SELECT t2.Value FROM Table2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.Attribute='Cardno') as Cardno,
FROM Table1 t
```

If you have more unique attributes then you should try [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) or [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) and temporary table to generate the table that you want

Comment: The _subqueries_ will work. Though in practice the SELECT statement becomes easier to read and maintain by using JOINs. Often, as in this case, JOINs improve performance