# Concatenate from rows in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I want to concatenate from multiple rows

Table:

```
|id      |Attribute   |Value    |
|--------|------------|---------|
|101     |Manager     |Rudolf   |
|101     |Account     |456      |
|101     |Code        |B        |
|102     |Manager     |Anna     |
|102     |Cardno      |123      |
|102     |Code        |B        |
|102     |Code        |C        |
```

The result I’m looking for is:

```
|id      |Manager|Account|Cardno|Code      |
|--------|-------|-------|------|----------|
|101     |Rudolf |456    |      |B         |
|102     |Anna   |       |123   |B,C       |
```

I have the following code from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144042/sql-join-a-row-table-with-a-column-table):

```
select
  p.*,
  a.value as Manager,
  b.value as Account,
  c.value as Cardno
from table1 p
left join table2 a on a.id = p.id and a.attribute = 'Manager'
left join table2 b on b.id = p.id and b.attribute = 'Account'
left join table2 c on c.id = p.id and b.attribute = 'Cardno'
```

However, it fails for the `Code` attribute with ID# 102, where both `B` and `C` values are present.

How can I update this to include both of those values in the same result?

Comment: Ah, the dreaded EAV schema anti-pattern. Sometimes you reap what you sow. Every field you want is another join back to the same table, and in the case of `(102,Code)`, you're in a for a real treat, probably using string_agg(). Also, we need to know **exactly** what kind of database you're using, because the correct solution will depend on both the database type and version, as some databases have added tools in recent versions to help with this.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: I forgot one important thing. I'm a beginner in SQL. Perhaps this is more complicated then I thought.

Comment: Well, `string_agg()` isn't available until Sql Server 2017. That would still have been a but of a pain (you'd need to group by each of the columns), but without it you're gonna have to do this the _really hard_ way.

Comment: Thank you Joel. I got a little hybris with the first problem. I've been working a lot with Excel but I must admitt that SQL has many advanteges. Guess I've to do the job in Excel. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL SERVER 2017 or above then `string_agg()` with `PIVOT()` will be easy to use but much faster in performance solution (`Query#1`).

If you are using older version of SQL Server then go for `Query#2` with `STUFF()` and `XML PATH FOR()` for concatenating value along with `PIVOT()`

Schema:

```
 create table table1 (id int, Attribute varchar(50) , Value  varchar(50));
 
 insert into table1 values(101     ,'Manager'     ,'Rudolf');   
 insert into table1 values(101     ,'Account'     ,'456');   
 insert into table1 values(101     ,'Code'        ,'B');
 insert into table1 values(102     ,'Manager'     ,'Anna');
 insert into table1 values(102     ,'Cardno'      ,'123');
 insert into table1 values(102     ,'Code'        ,'B');
 insert into table1 values(102     ,'Code'        ,'C');
 GO
```

Query#1 PIVOT() with STRING_AGG():

```
 select *  
 from
 (
     select t1.id,t1.attribute,
     string_agg(value,',')  AS value
     from table1 t1
     group by t1.id,t1.attribute
 ) d
 pivot
 (
   max(value)
   for attribute in (manager,account,cardno,code)
 ) piv
```

Output:

| id | manager | account | cardno | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rudolf | 456 | <emnull</em | B |
| 102 | Anna | <emnull</em | 123 | B,C |

Query#2 PIVOT() WITH STUFF() AND XML PATH FOR():

```
 select *  
 from
 (
     select distinct t1.id,t1.attribute,
   STUFF(
          (SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.value, 120)
           FROM table1 t2
           where t1.id = t2.id and t1.attribute=t2.attribute
           FOR XML PATH (''))
           , 1, 1, '')  AS value
 from table1 t1
 ) d
 pivot
 (
   max(value)
   for attribute in (manager,account,cardno,code)
 ) piv
```

Output:

| id | manager | account | cardno | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Rudolf | 456 | <emnull</em | B |
| 102 | Anna | <emnull</em | 123 | B, C |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8114e22deb86377a700ca2ea23e9863e)*

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Now I've got to merge this with my related question regardning concatenate column table with row table by using join. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for sharing input, output, dbname and your efforts. It's much easier  to solve the problem with that much resource. You question deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: "STRING_AGG only Server 2017+"
You can solve this task using CTE and STRING_AGG function, for example:

```
declare
    @t table (id int, Attribute varchar (100), [Value] varchar (100) )

insert into @t
values
(101,     'Manager',     'Rudolf'),
(101,     'Account',     '456'),
(101,     'Code',        'B'),
(102,     'Manager',     'Anna'),
(102,     'Cardno',      '123'),
(102,     'Code',        'B'),
(102,     'Code',        'C')

;with cte as 
(
select id, Attribute 
,STRING_AGG([Value], ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [Value] 
from @t
group by ID, Attribute
)
select
    max(p.ID) ID
    ,a.Value Manager
    ,isnull(b.Value, '') Account
    ,isnull(c.Value, '') Cardno
    ,isnull(e.Value, '') Code
from cte p
left join cte a on a.id =p.ID and a.attribute = 'Manager'
left join cte b on b.id = p.id and b.attribute = 'Account'
left join cte c on c.id = p.id and c.attribute = 'Cardno'
left join cte e on e.id = p.id and e.attribute = 'Code'
group by p.ID, a.Value,b.Value,c.Value,e.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method via XML and XQuery.

It is for SQL Server 2008 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT, attribute VARCHAR(20), [Value] VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, attribute, Value) VALUES
(101,'Manager','Rudolf'),
(101,'Account','456'),
(101,'Code','B'),
(102,'Manager','Anna'),
(102,'Cardno','123'),
(102,'Code','B'),
(102,'Code','C');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, (
        SELECT *
        FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE c.id = p.id
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')

    ) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl AS p
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT ID
    , COALESCE(xmldata.value('(/root/r[attribute="Manager"]/Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'),'') AS Manager
    , COALESCE(xmldata.value('(/root/r[attribute="Account"]/Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'),'') AS Account
    , COALESCE(xmldata.value('(/root/r[attribute="Cardno"]/Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'),'') AS Cardno
    , COALESCE(REPLACE(xmldata.query('data(/root/r[attribute="Code"]/Value)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), ','),'') AS Code
FROM rs
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Output**

```
+-----+---------+---------+--------+------+
| ID  | Manager | Account | Cardno | Code |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+------+
| 101 | Rudolf  |     456 |        | B    |
| 102 | Anna    |         |    123 | B,C  |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+------+
```